# Add a single file to gradle resources

Tags: resources, gradle

I'm using the config var plugin for heroku (see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).

It allows me to use a .env file which I do not push to source control to define the heroku environment.

So when I'm on heroku, I can access sensible information via System.properties.

In dev, I would like to read from this file so it would be best if it were on my classpath.

The .env file is at the root of my project so I cannot use something like this :

```groovy
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/resources', '/']
        }
    }
}
```

What is the simplest way to include a single file into gradle resources ?

Answer (score 9):

The earlier answers seemed more complicated than I was hoping for, so I asked on the [gradle forums](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-add-a-single-extra-resource-to-the-existing-resources/17070/2?u=lbergelson) and got a reply from a Sterling Green who's one of the gradle core devs.

He suggested configuring `processResources` directly

```groovy
processResources {
   from(".env") 
}
```

He also mentioned that it might be a bad idea to include the project root as an input directly.

Answer (score 5):

After merging the previous answer here with another tips from other sites, I came up with the following solution:

```groovy
sourceSets {
  specRes {
    resources {
      srcDir 'extra-dir'
      include 'extrafiles/or-just-one-file.*'
    }
  }
  main.resources {
    srcDir 'src/standard/resources'
    srcDir specRes.resources
  }
}
processResources {
  rename 'some.file', 'META-INF/possible-way-to-rename.txt'
}
```

I still wonder whether there is some better way.

Comment: This has the side effect of also adding a new `specResClasses` task which is probably not what's intended.  I repeated the question on the gradle forums to see if anyone there has a better way:  https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-add-a-single-extra-resource-to-the-existing-resources/17070

Answer (score 2):

What I ended up doing was to add project root directory as a resource folder including only the file I was interested in :

```groovy
sourceSets.main.resources { srcDir file('.') include '.env' }
```

Seems to do the trick. I wonder if it's the best solution thought

Comment: what if I have more than one dir, such as `A, B, C,` for dir `C`, I only need `C/my.properties`,but for `A` and `B`, I need all files

Comment: what do you do if you want to give it another name inside the jar?

Comment: This solution works but (as noted above) the "include" pattern is then used for ALL srcDirs, not just one. I wonder how it can be done to add one file to existing srcDirs.