# Include outside groovy class into sourceset

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I am trying to add a single groovy class (just an enum) that lives in the project root to my simple java/groovy module. I want the class to be accessible in my module’s java classes, but I also plan to add it to other (outside of the module) groovy scripts. I’m not having any luck though. So far I’ve tried various expressions:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        groovy {
            setIncludes(new HashSet(["$projectDir/foo.groovy"]))
//            from projectDir
//            include "foo.groovy"
//            include "$projectDir/foo.groovy"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can accomplish this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add a single file to gradle resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24207348/add-a-single-file-to-gradle-resources)

Comment: @AlexK. unfortunately not. I'm not trying to add resources, and that approach doesn't add a single file

Comment: Seems that it's rather hacky to set up. I ended up using a python script for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for that answer.
So far I managed to get the "exclude" work, so one workaround would be to exclude every file but the one you need. Another option would be to separate each *.java into its own dir and then use the srcDirs() to include/exclude whatever you need.
I know that's far from the best approach but enough to get through.